# Raphael is not defined using g.raphael-rails and raphael-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, raphael, graphael

I'm trying to do generate a sample bar chart for JSON data generated through Rails.

To start off, I'm just trying to simply see if my Rails app can generate the barchart.html from the [example](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/blob/master/test/barchart.html) provided in [g.raphael github repo](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael) .

I'm using [raphael-rails](http://rubygems.org/gems/raphael-rails) and [g.raphael-rails](http://rubygems.org/gems/g.raphael-rails) gem in my Rails 3.2.11 app.

Currently when I try to hit /companies/company_division_stats in the browser from my [sample code](https://github.com/boddhisattva/stores),  Firebug throws the below error:

```
ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined in corresponding to the line of code :-
var r = Raphael("holder")
```

The documentation from the two gems doesn't specify the need of including any js files to my application.js .

Interestingly, when I just try to do a run of the sample plain HTML below in my browser, I also get two errors.

1.

```
 ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined
 F.prototype = Raphael.g;

Reference g.bar.js(line 419)
```

2. `TypeError: r.barchart is not a function`

Sample HTML:

```
<!--<!doctype html>-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>gÂ·RaphaÃ«l Static Bar Charts</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo-print.css" type="text/css" media="print" charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Throws same error when using the raphael and g.raphael gem-->
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/master/g.bar.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/master/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/master/g.raphael.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      window.onload = function () {
          var r = Raphael("holder"),
                  data1 = [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55], [12, 20, 30]],
                  data2 = [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55], [12, 20, 30]],
                  data3 = [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10], [10, 2, 1, 5, 32, 13, 20, 55], [12, 20, 30]],
                  txtattr = { font: "12px 'Fontin Sans', Fontin-Sans, sans-serif" };

          r.text(160, 10, "Single Series Chart").attr(txtattr);
//          r.text(480, 10, "Multiline Series Chart").attr(txtattr);
//          r.text(160, 250, "Multiple Series Stacked Chart").attr(txtattr);
//          r.text(480, 250, 'Multiline Series Stacked Vertical Chart. Type "round"').attr(txtattr);

          r.barchart(10, 10, 300, 220, [[55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 2, 10]], 0, {type: "soft"});
//          r.barchart(330, 10, 300, 220, data1);
//          r.barchart(10, 250, 300, 220, data2, {stacked: true});
//          r.barchart(330, 250, 300, 220, data3, {stacked: true, type: "round"});
      };
  </script>
</head>
<body class="raphael" id="g.raphael.dmitry.baranovskiy.com">
<div id="holder"></div>
<p>
  Demo of <a href="http://g.raphaeljs.com/">gÂ·RaphaÃ«l</a> JavaScript library.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it fixed, thanks to inputs from my senior. Currently I'm simply adding them as JS in app/assets/javascripts and requiring them in my application.js

I need to define the js in the correct **order** .

--> Order in sample html code

```
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/master/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/master/g.raphael.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/master/g.bar.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

- Order in application.js

  ```
  require raphael-min

  require g.raphael

  require g.bar
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For one using Rails 4 and the [graphael-rails](https://github.com/cschwartz/graphael-rails) gem:

Add to application.js before the `require_tree` statement:

```
...
//= require raphael/raphael.js
//= require g.raphael/g.raphael.js
//= require g.raphael/g.bar.js // ...and g.pie.js etc
//= require_tree .
```

This gem helps by internally linking to Rafaël and g.Rafaël repos, helping to keep them updated.